# how to automatically set scm connection in maven pom?

Tags: maven, svn

We are trying to run `release:prepare` but this produces error like below.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:
        prepare (default-cli) on project test-module:
        Missing required setting:
        scm connection or developerConnection must be specified. -> [Help 1]
```

We want to avoid setting the scm.connection manually.

How to set `scm.connection` automatically to the current URL? - For SVN and git.

The information must be somewhere within the (metadata of the) module, since `svn info` displays the value under `URL`.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you should be able to set the developerConnection by using a parameter, but (thanks to khmarbaise for telling me) there is a bug (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-1017) so that this does not work at the moment.

I currently work around this with my own Maven plugin. It compares the connection and developerConnection entries of the pom with the url provided by the build server (the build server knows the url because it checked out the code) and adjusts the urls if necessary (followed by `scm:checkin`).